# Find the $\lim_{x\to -6} \frac{2x+12}{\lvert x+6 \rvert}\ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Find the Find the $\lim_{x \to -6}\frac{2x+12}{|x+6|}\ $
The limit changes on when -6 approaches on the negative side to -(x-6) which gives me a denominator in the bottom.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$|x|=\begin{cases}x&\text{if $x\ge 0$}\\-x&\text{if $x\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$
In our case, for $x\lt -6$, 
$$|x+6|=-(x+6)$$
not$$-(x-6).$$

So, we have
$$\lim_{x\to -6^-}\frac{2x+12}{|x+6|}=\lim_{x\to -6^-}\frac{2(x+6)}{-(x+6)}=-2.$$

Comment: So the only part I failed to do was factor the top?

Comment: @user137452: I guess so. I hope this helps.

Comment: my piecewise function looks like this:|x+6|=\begin{cases}x+6&\text{if $x+6\ge 0$}\\-(x+6)&\text{if $x\lt 0$}\end{cases} Is this okay to use?

Comment: No. It is not correct. $|x+6|=x+6$ if $x+6\ge 0$. On the other hand, $|x+6|=-(x+6)$ if $x+6\lt 0$. So, all you need to consider is the sign of $x+6$.

Comment: Is it correct now? I took the x out, that was a mistake.

Comment: Close, but not correct. The first is correct. For the second, $|x+6|=-(x+6)$ if $\color{red}{x+6\lt 0}$, not $x\lt 0$.

Comment: $\begin{cases}x+6&\text{if $x+6\ge 0$}\\-(x+6)&\text{if $x+6\lt 0$}\end{cases}\ $                                                         or $\begin{cases}x+6&\text{if $x\ge 6$}\\-(x+6)&\text{if $x\lt -6$}\end{cases}\ $

Comment: @user137452: Yes, perfect.

Comment: I cannnot evaluate the right side? (greater then -6). Is that correct?

Comment: @user137452: Note that $x+6\ge 0\iff x\ge \color{red}{-6}$. The rest is correct.

Comment: So I can evaluate the right side. Final question, is it best to make both of these piece wise functions when talking a test and if so why?

Comment: this function does not exist since two different values are calculated

Comment: @user137452: You don't always need both. It depends on the situation. All we need is to understand what it is correctly. P.S. 'The limit' does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2x+12}{|x+6|}=2\frac{x+6}{|x+6|}=\begin{cases}\;\;\;2&,\;\;x\ge-6\\{}\\-2&,\;\;x<-6\end{cases}$$

Deduce from the above that the one sided limits aren't equal and thus the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $x<-6$, $\frac{2x+12}{|x+6|}=\frac{2x+12}{-x-6}=-2$ and for $x>-6$, $\frac{2x+12}{|x+6|}=\frac{2x+12}{x+6}=2$.

Can you find the limit now?